# Multiple browser versions on OS X including IE

Tags: macos, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox, cross-browser

Does anybody know the application this guy uses?

[image]

Here is link to the video https://vimeo.com/45865290#t=1:07

Comment: Seeing the vmware running there I would bet on a bunch of virtual machines running in unity mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VMware Fusion is running in the Dock, so it's probably just a stack of shortcuts to apps from a VM that can run in Unity.

Apps can be added as Unity apps to the Dock per this VMware KB article:

- [Adding Windows applications to your Mac's Applications folder using VMware Fusion](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2005730)